# rsync copying from a server with differents permisions and owner

Tags: permissions, rsync

I'm trying to copy an entire folder with his content from a remote server to a new one, the remote server hasn't installed any pannel and new one has cpanel.

When I run the next instruction it looks to copy everything but it only has copied the folder and it's empty. The folder copied has permissions 700 like in remote but in new server the folders permissions are 755, of course the user and group are different.

I'm running this instruction with different options:

```
rsync -rlDv --no-perms --no-owner --no-group user@000.000.000.000:/home/user/public_html/folder /home/user/public_html/images/
```

I've used instead -rlDv -av with and without --no-perms --no-owner --no-group

Nothing works.

Any idea, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well, finally I've just fixed the problem.

The problem was that the files and folders was uploaded but I was seeing it with user own in cpanel and he can't see that files because the group and user was different, I changed in console to root and after change the owner and permissions to the same of the web and erything began to work fine.